# where do i find my yootheme templates customiser css file location

Tags: joomla3.0, yoothemes

I am using a yootheme template yoo_master2, and I created a new style for my site by going to

extensions->templates->"select styles from the left menu"->select template name->options->settings->customiser

I then made the changes required and saved the changes as a new style and applied them to my site. The problem I am having is I cannot find the newly created css file anywhere in my file directory.

can someone tell me where I can find it please? the yootheme documentation says this "The /styles/STYLE-NAME/layouts folder of your theme is at the top of the hierarchy and modifications or additions you make here will override all other theme files. Also this folder will be preserved during updates, so it's the safest place to make your modifications."

but I don't seem to have a styles folder anywhere?

appreciate your help
many thanks

Luke